# What is the most concise way to ascertain whether the program itself has a certain access right to a file?

Tags: c++, filesystems, std, file-access, c++17

**Question:**

Note that for the purpose of this question I will assume that a directory is a special kind of file.

Furthermore, I will assume (and please do correct me if I am wrong), that writing rights to a directory encompass the right to create new files within said directory.

`std::filesystem::perms` lists the following kinds of permission, each for the three operation types `read`, `write` and `execute`:

- `owner` : The owner *of the file*.
- `group` : The user group *of the file*.
- `others`: Everyone? (Not at all sure about that; please correct if wrong.)

Now, as can easily be seen, if one wishes to know whether the running program has a given right, this information is non-trivial to derive from these:

- Is the program's user the file's user?
- Is any of the file's user group one of or a child of the program's user group?

**Interestingly, there does not seem to exist any function in the library, which would correspond to the following function declaration:**

```
enum FileAction { READ = 1, WRITE = 2, RW = READ|WRITE };

bool canDo(const std::filesystem::path & path, FileAction action);
```

**How could such a function be implemented then?**

Of course, the good old pre-C++17 way would be to just try and start reading/writing and catch the exception if it fails. I would like to think that the Filesystem library has to offer a more elegant solution.

I am interested in answers applicable to Windows (XP+) and Linux. Please remark, if your answer only applies to one (even if one should hope that a universal answer does exist and can be found).

---

**Use case:** (Belatedly added to ward against "you should not ask this" answers.)

Ascertain at start of *a game* whether its own directory is in a valid state: No need to run, after all, if it would fail anyway.

We *can* assume that no other program will mess with the installation directory of an application. If we *cannot*, then the user and their system have bigger problems than a *malfunctioning game* and *we do not care*.

This is typically a local directory on a physical disk in a personal computer, which will not fail during operation (again, if it does *we stop caring*). Neither the user nor any other program will try to move files out of our installation directory or delete them or steal our permissions *because that is stupid* (or deliberate) and so, should that happen, *we stop caring*.

**As long as we still care, we wish to provide a *best effort* aka *greedy algorithm* aka *educated guess* as to whether we can expect to run successfully.**

The user might be a non-professional in dealing with their operating system and *require hints* to provide a working environment. We wish to provide all the hints we can and only then *stop caring*, because we are an application, not an OS and certainly not the system administrator.

We want to help the user if helping is possible with little effort, because we are nice. We are no samaritan and no superhero, just nice. We also have zero interest to try and intercept shenanigans the user might deliberately be up to, because then any resulting troubles are *their own fault* and therefore *we stop caring*.

It is *well established practice* for games to heuristically check their installation directory for integrity. Steam offers this as a service for all games installed through it. Star Trek Online, League of Legends, Warframe have launchers that do the same.

These games typically check file integrity by calculating (via *reading*) hashes of their files and comparing them to known valid hashes.

A game wherein *almost all files are intended for modification by the user*, such as Dwarf Fortress cannot do that. It *could*, however check for reading rights to files, which must be read, and for writing rights to files, which must be written. Again: there is no *purpose* in manipulating such rights while the game is running and therefore it should not be assumed to occur.

Comment: @ildjarn : Please edit with care and comment. The question body referenced tags which are no longer set after your edit; I fixed this. Also, it is harder for me to learn proper conduct, if it is left unexplained.

Comment: Try to tag your questions according to your anticipated answerer's area of expertise. In this case the `windows` tag is not likely to bring readers with cutting-edge C++ libraries knowledge, whereas `filesystems` may indeed bring experts with `boost::filesystem`/`std::experimental::filesystem`. `stl` is not a relevant tag since the Filesystem TS has no relation to the STL; `std` is appropriate, however. Lastly, all versioned C++ tags (e.g. `c++1z`) should always also be tagged `c++`.

Comment: Oh, and giving an explanation like this for every question that needs retagging is simply untenable. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn : Well, I for one am grateful for the explanation and will try to heed it. The difference between `stl` and `std` tags is arguably non-obvious, especially due to the last sentence in `stl`'s description, which seems to encourage its use to describe all the library.

Answer (score 3):

"Just try the I/O and handle failures" is still the best approach, for multiple reasons (in roughly descending order of the rate you'll run into them in the real world):

1. Predicting failure requires reproducing the OS's entire access control logic, which may very well be version-dependent.  Don't reinvent the wheel.
2. Predicting failure even if done perfectly only tells you about *now*, not what will happen when the I/O operation actually is attempted.  The filesystem is a shared resource and permissions can change.  This race condition is so common it has its own name: TOCTOU (Time of Check - Time of Use)
3. The I/O can still fail for a multitude of other reasons not related to permission (drive was disconnected by user, network went down, another process used up all the free space).

Ultimately you can't avoid the failure handling, and doing both permission evaluation and failure handling is adding complexity without any benefit.

I don't know why you brought exceptions into the mix -- simply open the file in the usual way (either `fstream` or `fopen`) and check the result.  `fstream` would give an object with `failbit` set, `fopen` would give `NULL`, and in both cases `errno` may help diagnose the cause.

Comment: Let's make it known now that exceptions for streams are the wrong way to go. The standard mandates it throws `failure` and no major vendor gives useful messages. Boost.Filestream is no better. And the TS Filestream is based on Boost. So the "classic" idiom is the only correct approach for the time being.

Comment: Guess I should have added my use case: If reading fails, it is a fatal error, aka "abort without diagnosis". If permissions are not set at program start, they will probably not be set on file access, so a more detailed error message can be produced - and the user will not predictably lose their data e.g. on failed save.

The library offers several means to diagnose a likely _later_ failure, e.g. via `exists` and `is_regular_file`. Whether the permission to do a given operation, no matter whether it would actually succeed, is available, is yet another valuable information to help the user.

Comment: There's also no magic bullet. If there was an extraction failure, `errno` will give a useless error message. Ideally, the code stored in the `failure` exception would be useful, and then you could compare it to a [POSIX category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/system_error). But as I said, I don't know if any vendor that goes beyond the generic error message.

Comment: @Zsar You will have to code it yourself. [Here's an example of what it would look like if it was implemented in a major vendor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3aaf7e1602bab22e).

Comment: @Zsar *If permissions are not set at program start, they will probably not be set on file access, so a more detailed error message can be produced - and the user will not predictably lose their data e.g. on failed save.*  What are you going to do if the disk fills up in the time between your check and the time you try to write data to the file?  You have to handle the IO failure when you try to write the data *anyway*.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The question can be generalized to "Can I give the user a helpful error message?" The answer is no without manual labor.

Comment: @AndrewHenle : If the disk filled up inbetween, that is a systemic fault. I do not expect an element of the system to handle a problem of the whole. Incidentally, try with any version of Windows what happens, if your C: partition fills up during operation. Do not expect graceful handling. Do expect a notice from the OS at about the same time the symptoms already show. I do not care about this cause for faults and neither should a user application - unless it were a disk space managing user application (aka bloatware?).

Comment: @Zsar *Incidentally, try with any version of Windows what happens, if your C: partition fills up during operation.*  So you give up and assume the OS is Windows and the user is writing to `C:`?  Either your code handles failures gracefully or it does not.  You're arguing for reasons for your code to fail and blame someone else.  Good luck with that.  My standards are higher.

Answer (score 0):

> Of course, the good old pre-C++17 way would be to just try and start
>   reading/writing and catch the exception if it fails. I would like to
>   think that the Filesystem library has to offer a more elegant
>   solution.

There is no "more elegant solution".

Any such purported "solution" would be susceptible to a [TOCTOU race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).

You can't reliably check for permission to do X and then try to do X in a separate operation.

Comment: There is a notable difference between `I am not allowed to read` and `I cannot read` though. I do not think that a program should expect files in its own installation directory to change permission within its lifetime either - whereas they may very well be setup incorrectly in the first place (UAC). If file permission has changed between check and access attempt, I would very much classify this as "not the program's fault" aka "I do not need to analyse this fault". Initially wrong permissions however are a frequent standard class of fault and detecting them early is a very desirable feat.

Comment: @Zsar *There is a notable difference between `I am not allowed to read` and `I cannot read` though.* That's what `errno` is for. If the permissions *can* change - and they *can* - your IO code has to handle the problems anyway, so you gain nothing. What you are asking for creates a bug that has [it's own Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) with 13 citations on it, and that bug was mentioned *by name* in both answers you received within minutes of posting your question. There's a reason computers have existed for decades and no one has done what you want.